# help diagnose the query result? or a possible bug?

Tags: openfda

I used the following query:
https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20130101+TO+20141231]+AND+device.device_report_product_code=LLZ+AND+adverse_event_flag=Y&limit=1

In the query, adverse_event_flag field was specified as Y. However, the result I got is report number 3363982 with adverse_event_flag=N. Could anyone help me figure out whether my query is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was a minor one with query syntax: You're using equals signs `=` when you should be using colons `:`.

For example, `adverse_event_flag=Y` should be `adverse_event_flag:Y`.

[The new query](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20130101%20TO%2020141231]%20AND%20device.device_report_product_code:LLZ%20AND%20adverse_event_flag:Y&limit=1) returns only 23 results instead of about 1300.

[The openFDA API basics page](https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/#query-syntax) has information about the correct syntax for these queries.